# how to send simple raw array in android volley

Tags: android, android-volley

Anyone know how to send post request with raw data in android volley ..?
I want to post this array list with headers.

```
[{
    "Name": "qwertytestinggfgfgf"
}]
```

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.put("Authorization", "my Authorization code is here ");
    return headers;
}

@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("name", "rahatamjid");
    return params;
}
```

[Here is a screen shot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4z07M.png)

headesr section is working  good.

Comment: What problem you are getting? Not able to send or any error

Answer (score 0):

Add more to Hashmap

Try like this,

```
@Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("name1", "rahatamjid1");
        params.put("name2", "rahatamjid2");
        params.put("name3", "rahatamjid3");
        params.put("name4", "rahatamjid4");

        Log.i("request","" + params);
        return params;
    }
```

This may helps you.

Comment: this not help me sir

Answer (score 0):

You better send request with json like this:

```
JsonRequest<JSONObject> jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,httpurl, jsonObject,
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "response -> " + response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, error.getMessage(), error);
    }
    })
    {  
    @Override 
    public Map<String,String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.put("Authorization", "my Authorization code is here ");
        return headers;
    } 
};
```

Comment: [{"Name":"qwertytestinggfgfgf"}]  is my simple array list.

that i want it to the server Please tell me the method  .

on postman this string is going in raw format and Api tested with post man working good.

Answer (score 0):

please try this and let me know:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
  HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
  String creds = String.format("%s:%s","USERNAME","PASSWORD");  //please adapt this to your auth type
  String auth = "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(creds.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
  params.put("Authorization", auth);
  params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");// 
  return params;
}
```

Comment: no issue with header method sir  issue is only how to send 
[{
    "Name": "qwertytestinggfgfgf"
}]

this array as perameters  in postman its going in raw format

Comment: ok, your `getParams() `  is correct.. please show how you are using this params in volley request

Answer (score 0):

Override getBodyContentType to jsonBody in jsonObjectRequest method

```
 @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
            }
```

then put your raw data in json object with key.
the root object should be jsonObject to post.It should not be json array

```
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("yourKey",value);
```